# How to retrieve user's data from google APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

For users who allowed the service to access their data I would like to implement a function to retrieve and handle these data.

When the user performs authentication for the first time, the following screen appears:
[image]

In google developers console I have created a service account, checked "Enable Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation", and downloaded json file and included it in the following code:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var fit = google.fitness('v1');
var key = require('../../config/meelio_google_service_account.json'); 

/*
This file contains following properties:
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "meelio-dev",
  "private_key_id": "***",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
***",
  "client_email": "mfit-205@meelio-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1022202xxx41842",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/mfit-205%40meelio-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
*/

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(key.client_id, key.private_key, 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/google/oauth2callback');

var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.write'];

module.exports.listUserDataSourcesTest = function(req, res){
    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, scopes, null);

    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        oauth2Client.setCredentials({
            access_token: tokens.access_token
        });
        // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
        fit.users.dataSources.list({auth: oauth2Client, userId: '104169835623446790746'}, function(err, resp){
            console.log(resp);
        });

    });
}
```

When google fitness function is executed (fit.user.dataSources.list()) it returns an error:

> "Unauthorized access"

As I am not sure whether the error is caused by inappropriate permission (or other) settings or wrong code, I would be very thankful if anyone could help out to solve this issue by suggestin a correct way to retrieve user's data and/or fix settings in google developers console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets/get) it is not possible to use other user's id:

> Retrieve a dataset for the person identified. Use me to indicate the
>   authenticated user. Only me is supported at this time.

Having available (e.g. stored in database) users token and access_token, it is possible to retrieve the data using the following function:

```
function listUserDataSources(access_token, refresh_token, res){
     oauth2Client.setCredentials({
               access_token: tokens.token,
               refresh_token: tokens.refreshToken
           });  
    fit.users.dataSources.list({auth: oauth2Client, userId: 'me'}, function(err, resp){
               res.json([resp]);      

    });
}
```